# Creating Shortcuts for an Installed Electron Application

Tags: electron, squirrel.windows

I have an electron application for which I use [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager) to compile and [grunt-electron-installer](https://github.com/electronjs/grunt-electron-installer) to generate the Windows installer package.

Upon installation I handle the squirrel events like so:

```
//...

  switch (squirrelCommand) {
      case '--squirrel-install':
      case '--squirrel-updated':
        createShortcuts(cleanUp);
        break;
//...
```

and the createShortcuts function just spawns a child process to call the `Update.exe (Squirrel.exe)` with the `--createShortcut=myapp.exe` arguments

This works, however, when the shortcut it generated it is named `Electron` instead of `myapp`.

I don't see any other ways to specify the output name of the shortcut, so how would I change the generated shortcut to say `myapp`?

Here is the snippet of the squirrel logs:

```
2016-03-20 10:34:35> ApplyReleasesImpl: Creating shortcut for myapp.exe => C:\Users\zeus\Desktop\Electron.lnk
2016-03-20 10:34:35> ApplyReleasesImpl: About to save shortcut: C:\Users\zeus\Desktop\Electron.lnk (target C:\Users\zeus\AppData\Local\myapp\Update.exe, workingDir C:\Users\zeus\AppData\Local\myapp\app-0.0.3, args --processStart myapp.exe)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further investigation into electron-packager I found a more detailed explanation about the resource editing [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/usage.txt).

using the electron-packager command line I pass these arguments to update the embedded electron exe information:

```
electron-packager ... --version-string.CompanyName="Company Inc." --version-string.ProductName="Product" ...
```

The grunt-electron-installer will look for this embedded application information to generate the name for the shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

If you use electron-forge, you may want to try a config that looks like this:

```
"electronPackagerConfig": {
  "icon": "Icon",
  "win32metadata":{
    "ProductName": "My App",
    "CompanyName": "My Company"
  }
}
```

More info here:
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) if you get painful with Squirrel. You can use the command as below to make your installer for Windows:
`electron-builder path/to/your-electron-packager-output --platform=win --out=path/to/your-installer-output --config=path/to/builder.json --target=win`

Sample content for builder.json:

> {
>     "win": {
>       "title": "My Production Name",
>       "icon": "path/to/your-icon.ico",
>       "version": "1.0.0",
>       "publisher": "Your Company Name"
>     }
>   }

P.s: You must install [NSIS](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/nsis/nsis-2.50-setup.exe?download) and add NSIS path into PATH environment before you run the above command.